Handschrift entziffern
Ich habe ein antiquarisches Buch erstanden. Eine Biographie des Chemikers August Kekulé (Autor: ein Chemiker namens Anschütz). Auf der Leerseite wurde mit Bleistift eine Widmung eingefügt. Ich kann alles, bis auf die dort enthaltenen Namen, mit etwas Phantasie entziffern.

Sie lautet:
"Karl #1 zu seinem Geburtstag, in freundschaftlicher Verbundenheit #2 z Hd #3 d. 11.VII.1949:"
Ich wollte fragen, ob hier jemand #1, #2 und #3 eindeutig identifizieren kann?

Gibt es noch eine bessere Auflösung von dem Scan?

Das ganze Scheitert tatsächlich an der Qulität der Vorlage, der Scan ist bereits jetzt besser als die Vorlage. Aber ich spiel mich gerne nochmal.

Ich denke,

#1 ist "Hamburg"
#3 "z. Zt. Kassel", "z. Hd." passt hier gar nicht


Ja, guter Punkt! Irgendein Tipp für #2?

Der erste Teil von #2 könnte "Alfred" sein. Danach muß ich passen.

#1 könnte auch "Hamberg" sein.

#1 möglicherweise auch "Homburg" oder "Homberg".

Vermute eher "burg" wenn ich die Schwünge mit den Entsprechungen bei "Geburtstag und Verbundenheit so ansehe müsste "burg" eher passen ob jetzt aber ein a oder o sein soll... Keine Ahnung geht irgendwie mittig weiter statt oben  (o) order unten (a).

Die #2 könnte ein Name sein; falls der Vorname mit "tt" endet kann ich ihn auch nicht entziffern, nur hypothetisch als ? Ulfrechtt ? Den Nachnamen aber lese ich dann als "Liefers" - wo das endständige 's' direkt in den Unterschwung übergeht

Scheint mir plausibel zu sein. Das würde das Problem mit dem Doppel-T/ziemlich-breiten-H lösen. Das machte für meine Begriffe die Trennung von Vorname/Nachname ziemlich schwierig.

Tonwert-Trennung um Auf- und Abschwünge besser zu sehen:


Ich lese das als

#1 "Karl Homburg" (könnte auch "Bad Homburg" sein; Hamburg/Komburg; -berg auch.)

#3 "z.H. Kaul" ("z. Zt. Kassel" find ich aber besser passend)

#2 Tricky... "Ulfrulttlichen"

so-und-so-kirchen ?
Ullrich Hichen ?
Alfred + Lißchen  ?
Alfred Hicken ? Hickens oder Hickey ?



Falls es noch jemand probieren möchte, das hab ich sonst raus bekommen:
K l f   |   rul   |  tt  |  l i c h e n
U__         enl      H      ki(r)ch en
H__         end      lt     licfben/beu
Kl_         aul             lißchen
Ul_         e__             lisfen(u)e
Hl_         z__
Ulf         _nd
Ull         _ud
Klleun      rich
Ulf
Ulfo
Ulfe 
KG

Ich glaub der Mann kann seinen eigenen Namen nicht schreiben?! XD
Edit:
Mir ist noch aufgefallen, das dass "r" recht auffällig ist, weil es so "rechteckig" geschrieben wird. Es kommt im Karl vor und in der Unterschrift 2x (4. und vorletzte? Position). Das würde die "Liefers"-Interpretation von BobbyJ stützen.

Alfred&Ließchen genial!   Danke für die Mühen & 5
